# Zoom in at touch point

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, matrix, zooming

I have a canvas that is about 4048x8096, when I try to zoom in, it doesn't zoom in at the gesture point, it always moves towards Point(0,0) which is the canvas's position, here is the code I'm using:
It also flickers when zoom limits are reached.

```
private void GraphSurface_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    var matrix = ((MatrixTransform)this.RenderTransform).Matrix;

    Point center = new Point(this.ActualWidth / 2, this.ActualHeight / 2);

    center = matrix.Transform(center);

        if (Scale <= ZoomInLimit && Scale >= ZoomOutLimit)
        {
            matrix.ScaleAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X, e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y, center.X, center.Y);
        }

        if (Scale > ZoomInLimit)
        {
            matrix.M11 -= 0.001;
            matrix.M22 -= 0.001;
        }
        else if (Scale < ZoomOutLimit)
        {
            matrix.M11 = ZoomOutLimit + 0.001;
            matrix.M22 = ZoomOutLimit + 0.001;
        }

    ((MatrixTransform)this.RenderTransform).Matrix = matrix;

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: see if [How to auto center the content in a scrollviewer while zooming](http://www.xaml.in/xaml/how-to-auto-center-the-content-in-a-scrollviewer-while-zooming) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo that zooms at the gesture point. Use the bottom example. The code is JS, not Java, but it should convert okay. Replace awesome_tiger.svg with your canvas object. Maybe that will give you a sample of what you need for your own code. Hope that helps.

http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/